# Positioning NextJS remote image with relative div parent

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am currently trying to make a Card component in NextJS that contains a NextJS image with margins and some text below it. I was able to get the card's outer shape to look as I wanted, but I am having trouble positioning the image inside of the card.

The image would stretch out and I couldn't find out how to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. I couldn't use the objectFit prop as it is deprecated. Setting the image position to absolute also didn't work, nor did setting the parent div to fixed, it just sets the width of the image to 0.

The `mt-4` class of the image's parent div also doesn't extend the outer div. The margin of the inner div just overlaps the outer div, which isn't my goal. I could fix this by setting the inner div to be absolute but that would result the image dissapearing.

Here's my current code:

```
import { ImageCard } from "../types/imageTypes"
import Image from "next/image"

export default function ArtCard({ imgCard }: {imgCard: ImageCard}) {

    return (
    <div className="shadow-lg shadow-zinc-500 rounded-2xl border-stone-700 w-80 h-[32rem]">
        <div className="mt-4 mb-2 mx-1 absolute h-3/4">
            <Image src={imgCard.link} alt={imgCard.meta.join(' ')} fill />
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```